# Store bytes of a file in a struct from serial

Tags: c

I have a serial communication, where I will serialize a binary file and send it to a microcontroller.

My question is how to store this file.

I thinked to use the structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t id;         // protocol
    size_t  data_size;  // to help know the file
    uint8_t data[1024]; // data bytes
} RECEIVED_FILE_t;
```

The file is a binary and can vary up to 50Kb, how would it be better to store it in this structure, reference it with a pointer or a vector? Which would be more efficient?

With a `uint8_t data[1024]` i can store up to 1MB file? (1 byte * 1024 = 1024 Bytes = 1MB) Is correct?

I can change this structure.

Comment: 1M is 1024*1024 bytes. 1024 is 1k

Comment: Use an established transmission protocol, that sends the file in packets. If the file data has variable size, how can a fixed (maximum) size buffer be useful?

Comment: 1024B is 1KB  (old-school), not 1kB. 1 KiB according to new nomenclature. 1024*1024B is 1 MiB.

Comment: which side are you talking about? the PC side, the micro side, or both? what is the micro doing with this data?

Comment: @yhyrcanus In the micro side, receiving the data via uart connection. The PC side is a java application, no problem. The micro just need save the data in memory.

Comment: The reason i'm asking is that a giant blob of data isn't usually useful; normally you'd want to parse it out into something the micro can use. If the micro is just storing it (eg in flash), you'd probably want to pack it into a format that's easy for your flash controller to handle, which depends on a ton of factors, and you often want to be storing it packet-by-packet. I wouldn't use dynamic memory allocation (eg `malloc` as suggested below) ever on a micro, but you could statically preallocate a "heap" of memory and keep track of it manually, and keep a similar structure.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t id;
    size_t  data_size;
    uint8_t *pdata; // pointer to data bytes
} RECEIVED_FILE_t;
```

Once you have the size, allocate memory and read the data there.

Pseudo code:

```
RECEIVED_FILE_t file;
...
int data_size = ReadSize(...);        // get the data size somehow

file.data_size = data_size;           // put the size into the struct
file.pdata = malloc(data_size);       // allocate memory for the data

ReadData(file.data_size, file.pdata); // read data_size bytes and put them
                                      // in the memory where pdata points to
```

I have no idea how you get the data size and how you actually read the data. `ReadSize`  and `ReadData` are just there to illustrate how you code could work.

Comment: Thanks! It is better than using vector. But do you know which would be more efficient to access the memory?